# SQL inner join with filtering

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
Table1:

ID  Date  

1   2022-01-01
2   2022-02-01
3   2022-02-05
```

```
Table2

ID   Date         Amount
 
1    2021-08-01     15
1    2022-02-10     15
2    2022-02-15      20
2    2021-01-01     15
2    2022-02-20     20
1    2022-03-01     15
```

I want to select the rows in `Table2` such that only rows past the `Date` in `Table1` are selected in `Table2` and calculate a sum of amounts of each subset and `max(date)` in `Table2` for each subset  `grouped` by ID.
So the result would look like

```
ID    Date         Amount
1     2022-03-01    30
2     2022-02-20    40
```

SQL newbie here...I tried an inner join, but wasnt able to pass the date filter along...

Tried query:

```
with table1 as (select * from table1)
,table2 as (select * from table2)
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on (a.id=b.id)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this with Snowflake:

```
--create the tables and load data

--table1
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID NUMBER, DATE DATE);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1,   '2022-01-01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (2  , '2022-02-01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (3  , '2022-02-05');

--table 2
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ID NUMBER, DATE DATE, AMOUNT NUMBER);
 
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,   '2021-08-01',    15);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,   '2022-02-10',    15);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(2,   '2022-02-15',    20);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(2,   '2021-01-01',    15);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(2,   '2022-02-20',    20);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,   '2022-03-01',    15);
```

Now obtain the data using a select

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, MAX(TABLE2.DATE), SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
  AND TABLE1.DATE < TABLE2.DATE 
  GROUP BY TABLE1.ID
```

Results

| ID | MAX(TABLE2.DATE) | SUM(AMOUNT) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-02-20 | 40 |

Answer (score 2):

Much like Paul, I would use a JOIN but I would put the clauses on the ON, so if you join to more tables, it's cleaner for the SQL optimizer to see what is the intent on a per table/join basis. I would also use aliases on tables and use the alias, so there is no room for confusion where the value is coming from, which again as a habit makes life easier when composing more complex SQL or cut'n'pasting into bigger blocks of code.

so with some CTE's for the data:

```
WITH table1(id, date) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (1,   '2022-01-01'),
        (2  , '2022-02-01'),
        (3  , '2022-02-05')
), table2(id, date, amount) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, '2021-08-01'::date, 15),
        (1, '2022-02-10'::date, 15),
        (2, '2022-02-15'::date, 20),
        (2, '2021-01-01'::date, 15),
        (2, '2022-02-20'::date, 20),
        (1, '2022-03-01'::date, 15)
)
```

The following SQL:

```
SELECT a.id, 
    max(b.date) as max_date,
    sum(b.amount) as sum_amount
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table2 AS b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.date <= b.date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| ID | MAX_DATE | SUM_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | 30 |
| 2 | 2022-02-20 | 40 |

Answer (score 1):

Not personally familiar with Snowflake but a standard SQL query that should work would be:

```
select id, Max(date) Date, Sum(Amount) Amount
from Table2 t2
where exists (
  select * from Table1 t1 
  where t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Date < t2.Date
)
group by Id;
```

Note that because you are only requiring data from Table2, an *exists* is preferable over an inner join and in almost all cases will be more performant than a join, at worst the same.